# iTunes Connect can't see my BundleID

Tags: ios, build-process, itunes

I am trying to submit a revised iPhone app for release on iTunes. I’ve tested the app in as many configurations as possible and created and saved an iTunes Connect record. But I can’t find a way to get the latest build to appear in the dialogue window of iTunes connect. When I click on Build ⊕ or click on the link Select a build before you submit your app I only see the previous build. I’ve renamed the bundleID for the latest build in Xcode but I can’t make this appear in the iTunes Connect dialogue window. What do I need to do ?[image]

Comment: Can you see your archived app in activity menu.

Comment: @ Lumialxk Yes, that helped, thanks. Also in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

Comment: @ Lumialxk, I tried this. Under General Information on iTunes connect, I can now see the original bundle ID. But in the build section of the iTunes connect form I still see 1.1 and 1.2 and the old upload date. Can I expect to see this change in iTunes Connect ? How long should it take before iTunes Connect recognises the changes I made in Xcode ?

Comment: Usually it takes less than an hour. And pay attention to your build version in Xcode, it should be same as that in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Your app's bundle id (i.e. com.yourcompanyname.appname) is tied to the admin page for your app. Changing the bundle id for your app effectively disassociates it from your app's admin page. Changing back your bundle id should resolve the problem if this was indeed your issue.

Your bundle id (Bundle Identifier) is displayed under the general tab for your app settings right above version and build numbers:

[image]

Comment: thanks, that confirmed what I thought. But when I looked at the earlier bundle ID I was surprised to find the original bundle ID in Xcode was $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER).

Comment: Right. This type of string is a reference key akin to an alias and used throughout Xcode. To edit your bundle ID go to **Build Settings > Product Bundle Identifier** instead as seen in my updated answer.

Comment: @ caxix, thank's for the clear explanation. When I changed it back to the original ID (as suggested by Lumialxk), I can only see what I had uploaded previously, namely, "1.1 (1.2) Dec 13, 2014 at 9:43 PM". Under General Information on iTunes connect, I can now see the original bundle ID. But in the build section of the iTunes connect form I still see 1.1 and 1.2 and the old upload date. Can I expect to see this change in iTunes Connect ? How long should it take before iTunes Connect recognises the changes I made in Xcode ?

Comment: Incidentally, my new version will be 2.0, and not 1.3, as implied by the message in the iTunes Connect dialogue

Comment: So by changing going back to the original bundle id - _which incidentally I suggested_ - you have one problem less which is great. But it looks like there are other issues. Since your original post has been addressed I suggest formulating other questions as needed and closing this one out. And no - you cannot expect iTunes Connect to update by itself. You app's admin page has a facility for adding a new version for that app. If you made a mistake when entering that version, you can correct it on that page. It is expected that the new app bundle you submit has that exact version number.